# Range-Doppler matrix

Tags: matlab, radar

I am working on a radar simulation to calculate the range and the Doppler frequency of a target. I would like to build a range-Doppler map or range-Doppler matrix. I do not know the steps to develop the range-Doppler map or matrix. I hope there is someone out there kind enough to help me.

Answer (score 3):

Its very simple: The time domain signal per range gate should be windowed (e.g. hamming, blackman-harris, etc.) to avoid ringing, then a FFT per range gate should be calculated. All that is left is to arrange everything in a matrix where each row is a frequency bin and each column is a range bin. (or vice versa).